# How to maintain cell colour characteristics when reordering?

Tags: swift, uitableview

My tableView cell has multiple views and elements such as textFields and Labels. When I am reordering my cells, the cell that I am reordering has its colours removed and is turned transparent. From what I've gathered, this is a default feature implemented by Apple. I am wondering how I can override this feature to prevent it from happening?

EDIT: here's the code for moving a cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        // deal with updating data source and deleting row
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
   //deal with updating data in data source
}
```

Comment: Please share your code. Otherwise it's difficult to tell what is it that you're talking about.

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly to share. When I put my tableView in editing mode, the cell that I am reordering becomes transparent. I’m wondering how to prevent that.

Comment: This is a normal feature implemented by Apple. I’m just wondering how to override it so I can prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably permitting cell reordering using things like `canMoveRowAt:` and `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:`. As long as you do that, you have no say in how the dragged image looks. You are asking the table view to use a built-in feature for you, and you must accept how it does that.

You can get a bit more control over what the dragged image looks like, though, by using the new (in iOS 11) drag-and-drop feature instead.

Comment: yes, I am using canMoveRowAt: and such. Thank you, I will check out drag and drop.